# strcpy() Delete everything else

Tags: c

I need to read a file and look for a word and replace with a new word but it's not working as it should:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

FILE * f = fopen("text" , "rb" );
if(f == NULL ){
   perror("error ");
   return 1;
}
char chain[100];
while(!feof(f)){
    fgets(chain, 100 , f);

}
printf("%s", chain);
fclose(f);
printf("\n \n ;D \n");
return 0;
}
```

And this is how I replace the old word:

```
char str[] ="This is a hiall samplesss friends string";
char * pch;
pch = strstr (str,"hiall");
strncpy (pch,"sam",5);
puts (str);
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What errors are you encountering? Have you tried to debug this yourself?

Comment: What is the relation between the two pieces of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `strncpy` is copying 5 chars from `"sam"` into `pch`. Note however that `"sam"` has only 3 characters, so it is copying the three characters plus the `\0` terminator. That's why it is "deleting" the rest of the string: it is adding a terminator right after "sam", so you are getting `This is a sam` in the output.

If you strncpy only 3 characters, you'll get this:

`This is a samll samplesss friends string`

If what you want is something like find-and-replace (i.e. replacing "hiall" with "sam" and getting `This is a sam samplesss friends string`), you need to move the rest of the string backwards. A simple `strncpy` won't work because the destination memory overlaps with the target. For this, you can either use `memmove`, or use an auxiliary buffer:

```
char str[] = "This is a hiall samplesss friends string";
char* pch;
char* old_word = "hiall";
char* new_word = "sam";
size_t len_old = strlen(old_word);
size_t len_new = strlen(new_word);
pch = strstr(str, old_word);
assert(len_new <= len_old);
if (pch) {
   char* rest = pch + len_old;
   size_t len_rest = strlen(rest);
   char* aux = malloc(len_rest + 1);
   strncpy(aux, rest, len_rest + 1);
   strncpy(pch, new_word, len_new);
   strncpy(pch + len_new, aux, len_rest + 1);
   free(aux);
   puts(str);
}
```

Note that this will only work if `new_word` is the same size or shorter than `old_word`. If `new_word` is longer, you won't be able to edit in-place (in the string `str` itself), unless the original string has extra memory for it (e.g. if you declared it with `str[1000]` to guarantee you can increase its size enough — then the code above would work). The safest approach if you can't plan ahead what size `new_word` is going to be would be to allocate a new string:

```
char str[] ="This is a hiall samplesss friends string";
char* pch;
char* old_word = "hiall";
char* new_word = "sam";
pch = strstr(str, old_word);
size_t len_str = strlen(str);
size_t len_new = strlen(new_word);
size_t len_old = strlen(old_word);
if (pch) {
   char* new_str = malloc(len_str - len_old + len_new + 1);
   ptrdiff_t pos_word = pch - str;
   strncpy(new_str, str, pos_word);
   strncpy(new_str + pos_word, new_word, len_new);
   strncpy(new_str + pos_word + len_new, pch + len_old, 
                                         len_str - pos_word - len_old + 1);
   puts(new_str);
}
```

(Edit: addressed issues pointed out by David Bowling in the comments.)

Comment: @DavidBowling: oops, I focuse on the explanation and the code ended up quick and sloppy. Improved it, thanks!